# C++ "invalid constructor"

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors

when I am trying to create a class which has a constructor which takes an object of that class by value, like for example:

```
class X{
    X(){}
    X(X x){} //Error!
};
```

then g++ complains the following for the second constructor:

```
error: invalid constructor; you probably meant ‘X (const X&)’
```

Dear compiler, no, I did not mean a const reference. This time, I wanted to do what I wrote: to pass the parameter x by value! Why is this invalid?

Comment: How would you invoke such constructor?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are trying to create a copy constructor, and a copy constructor must take a reference.  Otherwise, when you pass the x into the constructor by value, the compiler will have to create a temporary copy of x, for which it will need to call the copy constructor, for which it will need to create a temporary copy.... ad infinium.

So a copy constructor must take its argument by reference to prevent infinite recursion.

Comment: A Tour of C++ Third Ed. 5.2.1 `complex(complex z) :re{z.re}, im{z.im} {}`. Is this a typo in the book?

Comment: Looks like a typo.  Unless compilers got so much smarter while I wasn't looking. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Because

```
X(X x){} //Error!
```

needs a copy constructor. i.e itself i.e. recursive. i.e. When does it end?!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to implement a copy constructor, which works only by passing a reference to the object you want to copy.